# Swagger UI ignores authentication/authorization

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a JpaRepository that exposes REST API and security enabled. [Source](https://bitbucket.org/kilaka/eventlogger/commits/tag/swagger-ignores-auth). Example:

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

When trying to access using curl (`curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/users'`), I get `Unauthorized` error (401) which is **great**.

When using the same API using [swagger UI](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#!/User32Entity/findAllUserUsingGET), the response is OK (200), which is **bad**. See screencap below.

All the questions related to spring boot auth and swagger were about removing the security layer. I, somehow, stumbled upon a configuration that the security is disabled in swagger UI.

**Any idea how to enable the security layer for Swagger UI?** Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It seems that I was already authenticated but forgot about it. Leaving the question just in case someone has the same, very short, memory as I do.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my mistake. It seems that I was already authenticated but forgot about it.

When trying to access the same [URL](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#!/User32Entity/findAllUserUsingGET) from a fresh/clean browser (Incognito), swagger-ui requests authentication. See screencap below.

[image]

Comment: Can we use the same basic authentication like in the screenshot for swagger url (/swagger-ui.html) ?